How to define tempered distributions without the Schwartz space but enabling Fourier analysis?
Let $\mathcal S$ be the Schwartz space (say, over $\mathbb R^n$). It carries the locally convex topology given by the seminorms
$$p_{\alpha,\beta}(f) := \sup_{ x \in \mathbb R^n } \left| x^\alpha D^\beta f(x) \right|,$$
where $\alpha, \beta$ are multiindices.
The tempered distributions are the dual space $\mathcal S'$ of $\mathcal S$. These distributions are a subspace of the larger space $\mathcal D'$ of general distributions.
Question: Suppose that I do not know the Schwartz space. What properties single out the tempered distributions among the general distributions?
I would like to use a definition that avoids the discussion of the Schwartz space but which enables everything needed for Fourier analysis.

The idea is to switch order of integration to get: $\langle \hat f, \phi \rangle= \iint fe^{-ix\xi} \phi dxdy=\langle f, \hat \phi \rangle $. However, if $\phi$ has compact support, then $\hat \phi$ has compact support only if $\phi$ is identically $0$. The FT is a bijection on the Schwartz space, so $f \in \mathcal S \implies \hat f \in \mathcal S$

Yes, but can you characterize tempered distributions without the Schwartz space?

Yes not only one can define $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ without $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, but this was in fact the historical route followed by Laurent Schwartz.
Let $\mathbb{S}^{d}$ be the unit sphere inside $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. The sterographic projection gives a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to the open set $U=\mathbb{S}^{d}\backslash\{\infty\}$ where $\infty\in\mathbb{S}^{d}$ is the point from which we do the projection. This gives an isomorphism of spaces of distributions $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)\simeq \mathscr{D}'(U)$.
Restricting distributions on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d}$ to the open subset $U$ gives a map $r:\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{S}^{d})\rightarrow\mathscr{D}'(U)$. The space of temperate distributions is the image of this restriction map.
The original reference is "Théorie des distributions et transformation de Fourier" by Laurent Schwartz, in particular Section 3 about spherical distributions. The "S" used for the common notation for Schwartz space is for "spherical", rather than "Schwartz".
